# Every .h file in XCode Project is disappeared. What happened to it?

Tags: iphone, header, xcode4.2

I am programming iPhone applications, so I use Xcode and my Mac book every day. 
There has been no problems at all until yesterday but today every .h files in every Xcode projects has disappeared. I've got into a panic now. TTTT_TTTT I have to finish an app for tomorrow. Please help me, what happened to my Xcode, mac book or me?? T_T

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whats happened there ROMM, but I'd suggest right-clicking on Finder in your dock, hitting "Find..." and running a quick search for ".h". Might save you some time rewriting them! Chances are Xcode's just had a funny turn... Hope you find them!

Comment: thank you for your advice. what is worse I tried it already but there's no use.....ㅑ(

Comment: I'm sure you have but I'll ask anyway - have you checked your trash?

Comment: Yes, of course... so I can't understand at all why it happened. I've tried searching in the web, but couldn't get any solution..T_T OMG